# Pattern.DOTALL with String.replaceAll

Tags: java, regex

I have a multiline HTML document that I am trying to get some stuff from. I'm using java's regex (I know - XML parsers bla bla bla, just bear with me here please :) ).

```
    dfahfadhadaaaa<object classid="java:com.sun.java.help.impl.JHSecondaryViewer" width="14" height="14">
<param name="content" value="../Glossary/glInterlinkedTask.html">

<param name="text" value="interlinked task">
<param name="viewerActivator" value="javax.help.LinkLabel">
<param name="viewerStyle" value="javax.help.Popup">
<param name="viewerSize" value="390,340">
<param name="textFontFamily" value="SansSerif">
<param name="textFontWeight" value="plain">
<param name="textFontStyle" value="italic">
<param name="textFontSize" value="12pt">
<param name="textColor" value="blue">

<param name=iconByID" value="">
</object>
sjtsjsrjrsjsrjsrj
```

I've got this HTML in a string: input.

```
    input = input.replaceAll("<object classid=\"java:com.sun.java.help.impl.JHSecondaryViewer.*?object>", "buh bye!");
```

Obviously, it's not working. HOWEVER, I can get a pattern match if I use pattern.compile with Pattern.DOTALL.

So, my question is - how can I do something like Pattern.DOTALL with string.replaceall?

Comment: Aha!

Found the inline flag "(?s)". It's the equivalent of DOTALL if you place it at the very beginning of the regex. Problem solved.

Comment: Is this a major issue?  Can't you just call `Pattern.compile` etc., or write a wrapper?

Comment: Does prepending `(?s)` to the pattern work? It works in other languages, not sure about Java.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Attach `(?s)` to the front of your pattern :

```
input = input.replaceAll("(?s)<object classid=\"java:com\\.sun\\.java\\.help\\.impl\\.JHSecondaryViewer.*?object>", "buh bye!");
```

From the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL):

> Dotall mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression `(?s)`. (The `s` is a mnemonic for "single-line" mode, which is what this is called in Perl.)

Other flags work this way as well

> Special constructs (non-capturing)
>
> ...
>
> `(?idmsux-idmsux)`    Nothing, but turns match flags i d m s u x on - off

On a side note, if your goal is to remove unsafe objects from HTML from an untrusted source, please don't use regular expressions, and please don't [blacklist](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/01/whitelisting_vs.html) tags.