# Remove comments in a string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, comments

```
 private static String filterString(String code) {
     String partialFiltered = code.replaceAll("/\\*.*\\*/", "");
     String fullFiltered = partialFiltered.replaceAll("//.*(?=\\n)", "");
     return fullFiltered;
 }
```

I tried above code to remove all comments in a string but it isn't working - please help.

Comment: Did any of the below answer your q?

Answer (score 2):

Works with both `// single` and multi-line `/* comments */`.

```
String sourceCode =
         "/*\n"
        + " * Multi-line comment\n"
        + " * Creates a new Object.\n"
        + " */\n"
        + "public Object someFunction() {\n"
        + " // single line comment\n"
        + " Object obj =  new Object();\n"
        + " return obj; /* single-line comment */\n"
        + "}";

System.out.println(sourceCode.replaceAll(
        "//.*|/\\*((.|\\n)(?!=*/))+\\*/", ""));
```

***Input** :*

```
/*
 * Multi-line comment
 * Creates a new Object.
 */
public Object someFunction() {
    // single line comment
    Object obj =  new Object();
    return obj; /* single-line comment */
}
```

***Output** :*

```
public Object someFunction() {

    Object obj =  new Object();
    return obj; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about....

```
      private static String filterString(String code) {
       return code.Replace("//", "").Replace("/*", "").Replace("*/", "");

   }
```

Comment: actually i want to remove the all commented part of the string

Comment: Sorry, it was vauge by your question. ^^

Comment: can u help me  to solove this problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code

`partialFiltered.replaceAll("//.*(?=\\n)", "");`

With,

`partialFiltered.replaceAll("//.*?\n","\n");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `(?s)` at the start of your `partialFiltered` regex to allow for comments spanning multiple lines (e.g. see [Pattern.DOTALL with String.replaceAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500036/pattern-dotall-with-string-replaceall)).

But then the `.*` in the middle of `/\\*.*\\*/` uses a *greedy* match so I'd expect it to replace the whole lot between two separate comment blocks. E.g., given the following:

```
/* Comment #1 */
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    i++
}
/* Comment #2 */
```

Haven't tested this so am risking egg on my face but would expect it to remove the whole lot including the code in the middle rather than just the two comments. One way to prevent would be to use `.*?` to make the inner matching non-greedy, i.e. to match as little as possible:

```
String partialFiltered = code.replaceAll("(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/", "");
```

Since the `fullFiltered` regex doesn't begin with `(?s)`, it should work without the `(?=\\n)` (since the `replaceAll` regex doesn't span multiple lines by default) - so you should be able to change it to:

```
String fullFiltered = partialFiltered.replaceAll("//.*", "");
```

There are also possible issues with looking for the characters denoting a comment, e.g. if they appear within a string or regular expression pattern but I'm assuming these aren't important for your application - if they are it's probably the end of the road for using simple regular expressions and you may need a parser instead...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help someone:

```
return code.replaceAll(
                "((['\"])(?:(?!\\2|\\\\).|\\\\.)*\\2)|\\/\\/[^\\n]*|\\/\\*(?:[^*]|\\*(?!\\/))*\\*\\/", "$1");
```

Use this regexp to test `((['"])(?:(?!\2|\\).|\\.)*\2)|\/\/[^\n]*|\/\*(?:[^*]|\*(?!\/))*\*\/` [here](https://regex101.com/r/vI2iW5/2)