# How to remove all comments from string without affecting URL in java

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove all types of comments from my string without affecting the URL defined in that string. When i tried removing comments from string using regular expression some part of the URL also removed from the string.
I tried the following regex but the same issue  happening.

```
    String sourceCode= "/*\n"
                + " * Multi-line comment\n"
                + " * Creates a new Object.\n"
                + " */\n"
                + "public Object someFunction() {\n"
                + " // single line comment\n"
                + " Object obj =  new Object();\n"
                + " return obj; /* single-line comment */\n"
                + "}"
                + "\n"
                + "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040431/remove-comments-in-a-string";

    sourceCode=sourceCode.replaceAll("//.*|/\\*((.|\\n)(?!=*/))+\\*/", "");
    System.out.println(sourceCode);
```

but anyway the comments are removed but the out put is showing like this

```
    public Object someFunction() {
        Object obj =  new Object();
        return obj; 
    }
    https:
```

please help me to find out a solution for this.

Comment: Well, that last line is incorrect at first, it is not in a `String` so it should not be there (code can't compile with this). Now, you should check if `//` is in a String or not too

Comment: You're better off using a tokenizer which can read the source code and create tokens from it. You can then get the comment text and search for any URL within.

Comment: could you please give any suggested docs or give any examples using tokenizer.

Comment: For example, http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/TokenizingJavaSourceCode.htm, but there are many around there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^:]//.*|/\\*((.|\\n)(?!=*/))+\\*/`
Changes are in first few characters - `[^:]`. This means that symbol before `//` must be not `:`.

I usually use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to work with regular expressions. Select `python` language for your case (since languages use a little bit different escaping).

This is quite complex regexp to be read by human, so another solultion may be in using several simple expressions and process incoming text in multiple passes. Like

1. Remove one-line comments
2. Remove multiline comments
3. Process some special cases

Note: Processing regexp costs pretty much time. So if performance is required, you should check for another solution - your own processor or third-party libraries.

**EDITED**
As suggested @Wiktor expression `[^:]//.*|/\\*((?!=*/)(?s:.))+\\*/` is faster solution. At least 2-3 times faster.

Comment: Sorry to edit the answer, but I strongly suggest to replace `(.|\\n)` with `(?s:.)` or `(?s).`. `(.|\\n)+` will make the pattern extremely inefficient.

Comment: I really mean it, `(.|\\n)+` or `(.|\\n)*?` and these variations are performance killers when placed inside a larger regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your String by "\n" and check each line. Here is the tested code:

```
String sourceCode= "/*\n"
            + " * Multi-line comment\n"
            + " * Creates a new Object.\n"
            + " */\n"
            + "public Object someFunction() {\n"
            + " // single line comment\n"
            + " Object obj =  new Object();\n"
            + " return obj; /* single-line comment */\n"
            + "}"
            + "\n"
            + "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040431/remove-comments-in-a-string";

String [] parts = sourceCode.split("\n");

System.out.println(getUrlFromText(parts));
```

Here is the fetching method:

```
private static String getUrlFromText(String []parts) {
    for (String part : parts) {
        if(part.startsWith("http")) {
            return part;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For more specific this EXP should be use

```
.*[^:]//.*|/\\*((.|\\n)(?!=*/))*\\*/
```

Your provided pattern was not able to remove `/**/` portion of code if it is there.(If it is special requirement then its fine)

**So Your EXP is like :**
 [image]

**And it should be:**
[image]

For more understanding [visit](https://regexper.com/) and use your EXP `.*[^:]\/\/.*|\/\*((.|\n)(?!=*\/))*\*\/` it will show you graph for that.