# Java Regex to replace text between braces {...} including newline

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

How do I replace text between braces {...} including newline with regex in java?

I've seen many related questions about removing text within brackets but the main problem here is that if there's a new line in the middle of the match, it sort of seems to not match.

Any help on how to do that properly is appreciated, thanks!

Example:

Input:

```
text 1 {
text 2
text 3
}
```

Output after replacement:

```
text1
```

Comment: use `System.out.println("text 1 {\ntext 2\ntext 3\n}".replaceAll("(?s)\\{.*\\}", ""));`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500036/pattern-dotall-with-string-replaceall you can use `PATTERN.DOTALL` or prepend `(?s)`

Comment: By virtue of the fact you state Open-Clos brace, it reeks of balance text. Otherwise, why not just match `}{`. There is no real construct in language that doesn't parse _nesting_ syntax. Java doesn't support it. Move on, nothing to see...

Answer (score 1):

Learned that . is not literally every character.

I'm using

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\{(.|\\n|\\r|\\t)*?\\}","");
```

and now it's working.

Comment: Doesn't Java support the `s` modifier? Which will make `.` match any character.

Comment: use `System.out.println("text 1 {\ntext 2\ntext 3\n}".replaceAll("(?s)\\{.*\\}", ""));`

Comment: Well, the best way is to use a negated character class: [`"\\{[^{}]*}"`](http://ideone.com/KRUhD8)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this:

```
string=string.replaceAll("\\{(.|\n)*?\\}","");
```

I hope it helps.